# CGRectMake 4 Lines with horizontal displacement for each line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrectmake

I have a method:

```
-(void) generateButtons {
int positionsLeftInRow = BUTTONS_PER_ROW;
int j = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < [self.Model.buttons count]; i++) {
    NSInteger value = ((Model *)self.Model.buttons[i]).value;

    ButtonView *cv = [[ButtonView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake((i % BUTTONS_PER_ROW) * 121 + (i % BUTTONS_PER_ROW) * 40 + 205, j * 122 + j * 40 + 320, 125, 125) andPosition:i andValue:value];

    if (!((Model *)self.Model.buttons[i]).outOfPlay) {
        [self.boardView addSubview:cv];


        if ([self.Model.usedButtons containsObject: self.Model.buttons[i]]) {

            [self.usedButtons addObject: cv];

            [cv flip];

        }
    }

    if (--positionsLeftInRow == 0) {
        j++;
        positionsLeftInRow = BUTTONS_PER_ROW;
    }
}
```

}

So, my question is, how to make a horizontal displacement for each line, that the second line is displaced from 1st and 3rd for example.

EDIT:

My view with buttons now looks like this: (easy)

```
*  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  * 
*  *  *  *  *
```

but in some views i want that they are placed like this:

```
*  *  *  *  *  
 *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  
 *  *  *  *  *
```

I hope this is understandable...

Edit2:

This is now working!

But how can i make something like this with My cgrectmake:

```
  *
 * *
* * *
```

Edit3:

If i want to do something like this:

```
*  *  *  *  *  *
 *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *
 *  *  *  *  *
```

It makes this:

---

```
 *  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *  *
 *  *  *  *    *
```

Don't know why...

Comment: Can you do a rough sketch of how you want these to look and add it to the question? You should also give us some more details in your question as it's difficult to know exactly what you want. Do you want lines, or boxes? What is ButtonView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this easier by splitting up your code a bit. The line that creates the `ButtonView` should be:

```
CGFloat x = (i % BUTTONS_PER_ROW) * 121 + (i % BUTTONS_PER_ROW) * 40 + 205;
CGFloat y = j * 122 + j * 40 + 320;
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 125, 125);
ButtonView *cv = [[ButtonView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andPosition:i andValue:value];
```

This makes your code much easier to read and debug.

Now you need to adjust the `x` value for every every other row.

Add this:

```
if (j % 2) {
    x += 20; // set to whatever additional indent you want
}
```

So your final code becomes:

```
-(void) generateButtons {
    int positionsLeftInRow = BUTTONS_PER_ROW;
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < [self.Model.buttons count]; i++) {
        NSInteger value = ((Model *)self.Model.buttons[i]).value;

        CGFloat x = (i % BUTTONS_PER_ROW) * 121 + (i % BUTTONS_PER_ROW) * 40 + 205;
        if (j % 2) {
            x += 20; // set to whatever additional indent you want
        }
        CGFloat y = j * 122 + j * 40 + 320;
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 125, 125);
        ButtonView *cv = [[ButtonView alloc] initWithFrame:frame andPosition:i andValue:value];

        if (!((Model *)self.Model.buttons[i]).outOfPlay) {
            [self.boardView addSubview:cv];

            if ([self.Model.usedButtons containsObject: self.Model.buttons[i]]) {
                [self.usedButtons addObject: cv];
                [cv flip];
            }
        }

        if (--positionsLeftInRow == 0) {
            j++;
            positionsLeftInRow = BUTTONS_PER_ROW;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you a lot, its really much easier to read! working perfect. but now i have a second question to this. what have i to do, if i want to have 4 rows with different counts of buttons? for example: first row 1 second row 2 third row 4? do i have to define a BUTTONS_FOR_ROW1/2/3/4? and what will the code looks like for these?